# how to get a line that coincident with another line?

Tags: postgis

I have 2 linestrings:
Linestring 1 (-3 3, 6 8, 15 9, 22 13, 28.5 15.7) --> red color
Linestring 2 (0 4.66666666666667, 6 8, 10 8.44444444444444)  --> blue color

Actually both two linestrings are coincident

[image]

How do I get a part of linestring 1(red) that are not coincident with linestring 2 (blue) in PostGIS (as a multilinestring) ?

Comment: Welcome to GSE.  Please perform the due diligence of reviewing the documentation on spatial operators before posting questions for which a one line answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I think [ST_Difference](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Difference.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, the result is wrong, because there are some points in linestring 2 (blue) that are not part of linestring 1 (red). I have tried using both st_difference and st_symdifference, but the results are wrong

Comment: I mean that there are some points in linestring 2 (blue) that are no the vertexs of linestring 1 (red).

Comment: Perhaps you could state what output you expect, as ST_Difference answers your question as stated.

Comment: the output I expect is a multi linestring: fist part of red linestring, and the second part of red linestring -> multilinestring((-3 3,0.466667),(10 8.4444,15 9,22 13,28.5 15.7))